# How to link order of dynamically created components with other component order?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am just learning vue 3 and have the following problem. I use tabs library that provide only `tab headers` without `content panels`. So, my solution is the following:

```
<myTabs/><!-- < -- headers -->
<div v-for="tab in tabs" ><!-- < -- content -->
   <keep-alive>
      <component v-if="tab.active" :is="tab.component"></component>
   </keep-alive>
</div>
```

Tabs are created this way:

```
const tabs: Array<Tab> = reactive<Array<Tab>>([])
```

So, I have tabs and for content panel I iterate tabs and show only active tab content. The only problem of this solution is that when order of tabs is changed (after swapping), then the order of content != order of tabs.

For example, I have two tabs (0,1). After swapping the order of tabs is (1,0), but the order of content is still (0,1). So, when I activate tab1 I see content of tab0. Could anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: You could make `tabs` a [computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) property, which returns the ordered list of tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `v-for` items need a [`key` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) so that Vue knows how to track item rendering. Without the `key`, Vue defaults to the item index within the `v-for`, which in your case, causes undesirable `VNode` reuse.

To resolve the issue, apply a unique `key` (e.g., an `id` property) on each `v-for` item:

```js
<div v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id">
```